# Format Table Variable Output with FOR XML AUTO

Tags: sql-server, xml, explicit

Using SQL Server 2008.

I have a table variable with a single column and single row.

If I do this:

```
Declare @testsToRun Table ( testsId BigInt )
Insert Into @testsToRun
Select testsId From tests Where testsId = 10

Select Top 1 * From @testsToRun
For Xml Auto , Type , Root('testMessage')
```

I get XML that looks like this:

```
<testMessage> 
    <_x0040_testsToRun testsId="10" />
</testMessage>
```

When what I actually want is:

```
<testMessage>
    <testsToRun testsId="10" />
</testMessage>
```

If the row source is a table, that seems to work fine. When it is a table variable I get a child element label I don't want, I want `testsToRun` and not `_x0040_testsToRun`.

How can I rework my FOR XML statement/clause to give me proper output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead - use `FOR XML PATH` and define your output structure with the column alias(ses) you use:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    testsId AS '@testsId'
FROM 
    @testsToRun
FOR XML PATH('testsToRun'), ROOT('testMessage')
```

Gives me:

```
<testMessage>
  <testsToRun testsId="10" />
</testMessage>
```

Comment: While this changes my stuff from attribute-based to element based (making the whole message larger), it was easy enough to change my message reader code. This works great. Thanks!

Comment: @ScSub: how does this change to element-based?? It gives you `testsId` as an attribute - just like you specified in your original post....

Answer (score 1):

Try using an alias on the temp table:

```
Declare @testsToRun Table ( testsId BigInt )
Insert Into @testsToRun
Select testsId From tests Where testsId = 10

Select Top 1 * From @testsToRun testsToRun
For Xml Auto , Type , Root('testMessage')
```

Answer (score 0):

The *x0040* value is the internal name for the temporary table. You will get normal output when you select from a regular table (so.... the option could be to create a temp table, select what you want and drop it from the db).