# How to get rid of XML "_x0040_" attribute prefix in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, attr

I'm trying to export a table's content to XML, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPTABLE_Results ([@Id] int)

INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE_Results
SELECT 1 as [@Id];

SELECT * FROM TEMPTABLE_Results
FOR XML RAW('Node'), TYPE, XMLSCHEMA('Node')

DROP TABLE TEMPTABLE_Results
```

But the result has an annoying "*x0040*" prefix in the attribute:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" targetNamespace="Node" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="Node">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="_x0040_Id" type="sqltypes:int" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<Node xmlns="Node" _x0040_Id="1" />
```

I was previously using a table-type variable, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3347840/402789), the prefix is added when the table is temporary; but even with a regular table, the prefix is still there.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found: no need to specify "@" for field in order to get it as an attribute instead of an element.

This yields the desired result:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPTABLE_Results (Id int)

INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE_Results
SELECT 1 as Id;

SELECT * FROM TEMPTABLE_Results
FOR XML RAW('Node'), TYPE, XMLSCHEMA('Node')

DROP TABLE TEMPTABLE_Results
```

The resulting XML is:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" targetNamespace="Node" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="Node">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="Id" type="sqltypes:int" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<Node xmlns="Node" Id="1" />
```